# 3 Row Single Column Image + Text Sidebar

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am a HTML/CSS newbie looking for some advice on how to create a 3-row single column layout with images and text right next to each other. I tried creating a separate code for just the text column using the flexbox model and that worked in a way but I am still having trouble aligning them and getting them to look right. Wondering if anyone else can suggest a better way to create a sidebar column with images and text right next to each other? Here is what I have so far.

```css
.imagecards {
  width: 450px;
  height: 900px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: auto;
}

.sidebarcontainer img {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px 30px 0 0;
  object-fit: contain;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.sidebarcontainer1 {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(228, 228, 228);
}

.sidebarcontainer1 img {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
}

`.sidebarcontainer_text` {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  align-items: left;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="imagecards">


  <div class="sidebarcontainer">
    <img src="resources/images/information-orientation.jpg">
    <div class="sidebarcontainer_text">
      <h1>Fisma: Design and Prototype</h1>
      <p>Designer Showcase of new Prototype Product</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="sidebarcontainer">
    <img src="resources/images/information-orientation.jpg">
    <div class="sidebarcontainer_text">
      <h1>Fisma: Design and Prototype</h1>
      <p>Designer Showcase of new Prototype Product</p>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="sidebarcontainer">
    <img src="resources/images/information-orientation.jpg">
    <div class="sidebarcontainer_text">
      <h1>Fisma: Design and Prototype</h1>
      <p>Designer Showcase of new Prototype Product</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You forgot to add the CSS code

Comment: Hi Roko, Thanks for letting me know. I'll add it now

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add flexbox layout to the parent of the two columns in the row.`.sidebarcontainer { display: flex; }`
The default direction is row so the text is placed right aligned to each other. I have added a few more edits and additions for snippet styling.

```css
.imagecards {
  width: 600px;
  height: 900px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: auto;
}

.sidebarcontainer img {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px 30px 0 0;
  object-fit: contain;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.sidebarcontainer1 {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(228, 228, 228);
}

.sidebarcontainer1 img {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
}

.sidebarcontainer_text {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  align-items: left;
  text-align: left;
}

.sidebarcontainer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="imagecards">


  <div class="sidebarcontainer">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?grayscale">
    <div class="sidebarcontainer_text">
      <h1>Fisma: Design and Prototype</h1>
      <p>Designer Showcase of new Prototype Product</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="sidebarcontainer">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?grayscale">
    <div class="sidebarcontainer_text">
      <h1>Fisma: Design and Prototype</h1>
      <p>Designer Showcase of new Prototype Product</p>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="sidebarcontainer">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?grayscale">
    <div class="sidebarcontainer_text">
      <h1>Fisma: Design and Prototype</h1>
      <p>Designer Showcase of new Prototype Product</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! This helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: flex` for the containers as well:

```css
/*QuickReset*/ * {margin:0; box-sizing: border-box; }

.imagecards {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: auto;
  width: 540px;
}
.sidebarcontainer {
  border: 1px solid #444;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.sidebarcontainer img {
  width: 250px;
  min-height: 250px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.sidebarcontainer_text {
  padding: 0 20px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.sidebarcontainer_text h1 {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="imagecards">

  <div class="sidebarcontainer">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/400/300">
    <div class="sidebarcontainer_text">
      <h1>Fisma: Design and Prototype</h1>
      <p>Designer Showcase of new Prototype Product</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="sidebarcontainer">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300">
    <div class="sidebarcontainer_text">
      <h1>Fisma: Design and Prototype</h1>
      <p>Designer Showcase of new Prototype Product</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="sidebarcontainer">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/450/300">
    <div class="sidebarcontainer_text">
      <h1>Fisma: Design and Prototype</h1>
      <p>Designer Showcase of new Prototype Product</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Super helpful! Thanks!!